# How come my forEach loop gets error when sending emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email, template-engine

I am sure the answer is staring at me right in the face but I'm a bit confused. I have a spreadsheet with employee information and I created a forEach loop (below) so that at the end of each row it should send an email with information from the row. However, the HTML file is not recognizing value[0], value[1], etc and I am getting the following error message: ReferenceError: value is not defined

```
function ncnsEmailFunction () {

const values = ncnsSheet.getRange(2, 1, 10, 6).getValues();

values.forEach(function(value, index){
if (value[0] === "") return;

const htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("NCNSEmailTemplate").evaluate().getContent();
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
  subject: `NCNSEmailTemplate`,
  htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });

})

}
```

Here is what my HTML file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

Hello <?=value[0]?>

  </body>
</html>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: ncnsSheet is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ncnsEmailFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ncnsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your sheet name")
  const values = ncnsSheet.getRange(2, 1, 10, 6).getValues();
  values.forEach(function (value, index) {
    if (value[0] === "") return;
    let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("NCNSEmailTemplate");
    t.value = value[0];
    const htmlBody = t.evaluate().getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),subject: `NCNSEmailTemplate`,htmlBody: htmlBody});
  })
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
Hello <?=value?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok perfect! I was just playing around with the following line and it helped fix the issue, this is good to know for future projects: t.value = value[0];